# failed to parse stage name "postgres:": invalid reference format

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a problem while building docker. Error is following:

```
     => => transferring dockerfile: 327B                                       0.0s
     => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to parse stage name "postgres:": invalid reference format
ERROR: Service 'postgres' failed to build : Build failed
```

I tried to find what was the problem, but still stuck with this, so I kindly ask for your help. This is the Docker file:

```
FROM postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}

ARG TZ=UTC
ENV TZ ${TZ}
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && chown -R postgres:root /var/lib/postgresql

#COPY my.cnf /etc/postgresql/conf.d/my.cnf

CMD ["postgres"]

EXPOSE 5432
```

Not sure what can be the problem here, but I'm getting an error mentioned previously. Thank you in advance for your help.

UPDATE:
It was an error due to problems with reading version of postgres, as @Makariy mentioned in comment.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should add variable POSTGRES_VERSION

```
ARG POSTGRES_VERSION
FROM postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}
...
```

And then build image `docker build --build-arg POSTGRES_VERSION=9.6 .` for example

Also this [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact) could be helpful

Comment: Sorry, there's a version, I forgot to paste it here

Comment: In your error log seems like docker dont get value of version

Comment: Makariy exactly. I added version manually and it worked.

Comment: This helped on an internet search landing here...(to find from the docs link above) putting the ARG before the "first" FROM can be reused for builder images like SDK containers (Dockerfile build steps) to copy into a runtime base images.THANKS!